# D3/Shiny Example Doesn't Display Bars

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny, rstudio

Following RStudio's instructions here under Shiny to D3:
https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/articles/shiny.html#shiny-to-d3

I updated to Rstudio (1.2.1015), r2d3 (0.2.2), shiny (1.1.0)

When I try their example code, instead of individual bars, I see this in the Rstudio Viewer.

[image]

The example R code is:

```
library(shiny)
library(r2d3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(
    sliderInput("bar_max", label = "Max:",
                min = 10, max = 110, value = 10, step = 20)
  ),
  d3Output("d3")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$d3 <- renderD3({
    r2d3(
      floor(runif(5, 5, input$bar_max)),
      script = system.file("examples/baranims.js", package = "r2d3")
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The path returned by system.file("examples/baranims.js", package = "r2d3") is /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/r2d3/examples/baranims.js

which is this file:

```
var barHeight = Math.floor(height / data.length);

var bars = r2d3.svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(r2d3.data);

bars.enter()
    .append('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d) { return d * width; })
      .attr('height', barHeight)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * barHeight; })
      .attr('fill', 'steelblue');

bars.exit().remove();

bars.transition()
  .duration(100)
  .attr("width", function(d) { return d * width; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work OK if data is all < 1
Not sure why this statement is used.

floor(runif(5, 5, input$bar_max))